# Close responsive navbar automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap responsive navbar. When the navbar is collapsed and I open the menu and click on a menu item, the menu doesn't close automatically, and I have to do it myself manually.

Is it possible to make the menu close automatically after clicking on one of the buttons?

Comment: Be aware that all the below answers since this comment date will also prevent you to click a dropdown within the menu itself.

Comment: But the Aug-Sep answers with `a:not(.dropdown-toggle)` do allow you to click a dropdown. But also be aware that almost all these answers give a FOUC when viewed on a desktop, or do a visible menu redraw. A quick hack to fix this is to select on window size: `if($(window).width() < 480) $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');`

Comment: I wish this was provided as default behavior by twitter bootstrap

Comment: @kittu Indeed! It should be default behaviour. Luckily I use no JavaScript and use `data-bs-toggle`, see my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808063/10686802

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Edit:**
As [Maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941444/341692) points out below, the **3.x bootstrap** solution is:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yohuLuj2/

---

Old Answer for **2.x bootstrap**:

You should be able to do that by adding a click handler to the list items and then closing the nav that way.

```js
$('.nav-collapse').click('li', function() {
    $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Heres a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/By6ym/4/

Comment: Don't forget to manually reset the button appearance: $('.navbar-toggle').addClass('collapsed');

Comment: isn't it `.navbar-collapse` ?

Comment: I am trying to do the same in Device inspection tool of Chrome 58. It's not working over there. Can someone suggest an alternative or tell the problem?

Answer (score 46):

Working solution for bootstrap 3

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: That was the one for me on BT3

Comment: does that still work if you have a dropdown in the menu?

Answer (score 34):

I just replicate the two attributes of the `btn-navbar` (`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"`) on each link like this:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <ul class="nav" >
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: A non-jquery solution works much better and is more maintainable!

Comment: Best answer here if you're using a framework such as Angular and don't want to clutter up the controller.

Comment: If you ever use this on a non-collapsed menu, you still get the collapse affect, which looks very weird.

Comment: @Stony You have to add `.in` to the end of the `data-target` value: `data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"`. From comment in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21797534/89818

Answer (score 11):

Only thing I'd add to jason's solution is the exception for dropdowns. You don't want to close your menu if someone is simply clicking to toggle the submenu. So…

```
$('.navbar-collapse a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

@Mike's dropdown solution worked for me except that the items within the dropdown toggle wouldn't hide the menu so I made sure to add this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse .dropdown-menu').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remember to traverse up the DOM tree and close the associated Navbar, and not all Navbars. In particular for Bootstrap 3, use something similar to the following code snippet:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".navbar-collapse a", function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  setTimeout(function() {
     $this.closest(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  }, 350);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another problem is when you see the navbar on desktop, it try to hide/show the navbar, so I made this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 768 )
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but your addition(`$(window.width()`) prevents a nasty FOUC when viewed on a desktop site, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

I complete the answers by adding button click management:

```
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.collapse.in a:not(.dropdown-toggle)', function() {
    $(this).closest(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.collapse.in button:not(.navbar-toggle)', function() {
    $(this).closest(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Changed the query selector by adding: '.collapse.in' to select only opened navbar.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, I was creating single page layout with anchors. So, when you downsize the window, menu hide on link click perfectly. *Thanks to above user who gave me clue.* But, when upsize window, the bind event always there (without reloading, though). So, here what I did. Hope it helps someone :)

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
    $('ul#menu-menu-with-anchors li a, a[href="#top"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - ($('body').hasClass('admin-bar') ? 160 : 130)
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });

    bindUnbindNavToggle($);
    $(window).resize(function(){
        bindUnbindNavToggle($);
    });

})(jQuery);

function bindUnbindNavToggle($){
    if( $('button.navbar-toggle').css('display') != 'none' ) {
        $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function(){
           $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            return false;
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function(){
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular, you can bind the collapsing to the route navigation:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code in main.js

```
 $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone need to hide menu when just click to somewhere else (i have supposed like there is no submenus). Then just add this code somewhere after jquery, bootstrap.js

```
$('button.navbar-toggle').focusout(function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ZU1779 answer is my favourite.

Anyway with component-based implementations (like Bootstrap-vue) will not work.

In this case you could add an event listener on links that call a function that emulates the click on collapse button, link this:

```
collapseNav = function() {
  document
    .getElementsByClassName('navbar-toggler')[0]
    .dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
}
```

Hope could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 5.3 - update 2023

All the answers here are either very outdated doing things with jQuery or don't work anymore.

### The following works with Bootstrap 5.2 and up:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu-navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="/">
            <span data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu-navbar">Home</span>
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link d-none d-lg-block" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### MRE of a navbar

See example below of a navbar with 2 menu items:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <!-- Replace SVG below for your own logo -->
            <svg width="40" height="40">
                <image xlink:href="https://svgsilh.com/svg_v2/1801287.svg" width="40" height="40"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu-navbar"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu-navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="/">
                    <span data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu-navbar">Home</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link d-none d-lg-block" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

#### Why 2 links in a nav-item?

Because if you use `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu-navbar"` your menu will "flash/reload" on desktop too, so the first link will hide on lg and wider screens and the second link will do the opposite, hide on screens smaller than lg