# Hide Twitter Bootstrap nav collapse on click

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is not a submenu dropdown, the category is class li as in the picture:

[image]

> By selecting a category from the responsive menu (the template is just
> one page), I want to hide nav collapse automatically when clicking.
> Also stroll to use as navigation, since the template has only one
> page. I seek a solution that does not affect it, here is the HTML code
> of menu:

```
    <!-- NAVBAR
  ================================================== -->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Carousel Demo</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" >
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <!-- dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav -->
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: and my solution working or not?

Comment: @WooCaSh Worked rather the order of their solution custom.js was wrong, I noticed $ ('nav a'). On ('click', function () {and in my case it is a class, then $ ('. nav a '). on (' click ', function () {. thank you, you helped me a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close responsive navbar automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248194/close-responsive-navbar-automatically)

Comment: If you don't want to try and compare all these solutions here yourself, [edit #1 from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23171593/89818) is what you should do.

Comment: You could see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248194/close-responsive-navbar-automatically#answer-26191027

Comment: **Bootstrap 4** method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401606/how-to-hide-collapsible-bootstrap-4-navbar-on-click/42401686

Comment: @TimVitor I have added an updated answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808109/10686802

Answer (score 166, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('.btn-navbar').click(); //bootstrap 2.x
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(); //bootstrap 3.x by Richard
    $('.navbar-toggler').click(); //bootstrap 4.x
});
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks WooCaSh. Also just suggested adding a "." to the code before $('nav a') => $('.nav a').  [Class selector was missing a dot "."]

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work in all cases. If the window is re sized and it brings up the mobile menu it will be open by default.

Comment: UPDATE: Usual selector for bootstrap 3 is .navbar-toggle, so $(".navbar-toggle").click();

Comment: If you have dropdowns in your navbar, you don't want to collapse when clicking on the dropdown. This worked for me: $('.nav :not(.dropdown) a').on(...

Comment: This is causing issues in the navbar. Better to use $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide'); on click event rather than making the toggle button click.

Comment: Thanks @Ronan, after trying all the solutions, yours is the best one on mobile and desktop. You saved my day and should get the "correct answer".

Comment: When the navbar is open in "desktop" mode it will flicker or close then reopen when using this.

Comment: jQuery('.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse'); was the most effective method in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: when menu is open you can see there is "in" class active

    `<div class="navbar-collapse text-center collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">`

just need to remove "in" there and it worked
    `$('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');`

Comment: The collapsing of the navigation should be done with bootstrap. You've build it with bootstrap, fix it with bootstrap if possible: look at Zu1779's answer and the comments. Way cleaner and makes a way more sense. The way to handle it is available in bootstrap itself, why ignore that?

Answer (score 135):

I just replicate the 2 attributes of the `btn-navbar` (`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in"`) on each link like this:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <ul class="nav" >
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the [Bootstrap 4 Navbar](http://www.codeply.com/go/jxBG9LPHFy), `in` has changed to `show` so the syntax would be:

`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"`

Comment: Adding `data-toggle` and `data-target` to <li> is cleaner solution. Thanks.

Comment: Works well on mobile, but causes the navbar collapse animation on desktop too, which is undesirable.

Comment: Gives a navbar animation (quick expand/collapse) on navbar item clicks.  This happens even when the collapse button is not shown.  Not ideal.

Comment: @JamesBrewer To avoid the collapse animation on the desktop version add `.in` to the data-target:
`data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in"`

Comment: I like this no-manual-script version. Better with other frameworks

Comment: Don't forget to replace .nav-collapse with .navbar-collapse for bootstrap 3

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thank you for posting it!

Comment: Would adding this to the body element be a bad idea if I wanted to collapse the menu if someone clicks anywhere on the page?

Comment: Putting this on <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"> works for all the <li> under it, you can avoid repeating this line.

Comment: Awesome! I was adding Jquery and had issues with animation and you saved the day! Cheers

Comment: @Zeus approach was the only one that worked 100% on both! Thanks!

Answer (score 61):

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav a').on('click', function(){ 
        if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
            $('.navbar-toggle').trigger( "click" );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a better solution, because it prevents a glitch when links are  visible.

Comment: On Bootstrap 4, it's `.navbar-toggler` . Anyway, super working code, thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Better to use default collapse.js methods
([V3 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-methods), [V4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-methods)):

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Definitely better than using the click functions! It's best to keep risk to a minimum by interacting only with the things you want to change. A click event could cause additional unwanted functions to execute. Didn't know about this collapse method, thanks.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far. Thank you.
Just a little improvement I made : replace the `.nav a` selector by this one : `.nav a:not(.dropdown-toggle)`

Comment: For me, on my bootstrap 4 example page, instead of `.nav a` I had to use `.navbar a`

Comment: Don't you mean `.navbar-collapse` and not `.nav-collapse` ?

Comment: No, I don't, because `.nav-collapse` was used in question  code example.

Answer (score 31):

Even more elegant without a lick of duplicated code, is to simply apply the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target=".nav-collapse"` attributes to the nav itself:

```
<nav class="nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Super clean, no JavaScript required. Works great, so long as your your `nav a` elements have plenty enough padding for fat fingers, and you aren't preventing click event bubbling via `e.stopPropagation()` when users click on `nav a` items.

Comment: This is the proper bootstrap way of accomplishing this behaviour.

Comment: I would suggest modifying the target to include the _in_ class as well. This will prevent the desktop versions from behaving weirdly.   `data-target=".nav-collapse.in"`

Comment: The nicer thing about this is it works with angular 4's routerLink whereas the other solutions don't!

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 it would be `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">`

Answer (score 17):

Update your

```
<li>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</li>
```

to

```
<li>
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" href="#about">About</a>
</li>
```

This simple change worked for me.

Ref: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9013

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly with standard bootstrap conventions.

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct way to accomplish this. No need for jQuery. I don't understand why this has gotten so little upvotes / attention.

Comment: On a "standard" Visual Studio master page, this will result in the burger menu disappearing and no menu options. This answer only works with a specific menu configuration layout (which you do not provide as an example).

Comment: This would no longer work. use `data-target=".navbar-collapse.in"` as with the new bootstrap standard. The `.in` class is to prevent the animation when on desktop

Comment: I've used this solution in my situation, but have used the ID of my `div.navbar-collapse` element as the `data-target` parameter.

Comment: This is the best solution for someone using Angular, where mixing up jquery is out of consideration

Comment: You just became today's god for me :). I just got this thing working after 3 hours of useless search on google. Pure basics.

Answer (score 13):

The navigation should be closed any time a user clicks anywhere on the body - not just navigation elements. Say menu is open, but user clicks in the page body. User expects to see menu close.

You also have to make sure toggle button is visible, otherwise a jump is seen in menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$("body").click(function(event) {
        // only do this if navigation is visible, otherwise you see jump in navigation while collapse() is called 
         if ($(".navbar-collapse").is(":visible") && $(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible") ) {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
        }
  });

});
```

Comment: "Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document." Your code was meant to prevent the collapse if the navbar-collapse is not visible on the screen, but it does not.

Comment: Not just that it works great, but it's also the only solution that worked for me, bootstrap > 3.

Answer (score 13):

Tested on Bootstrap 3.3.6 - work's!

```js
$('.nav a').click(function () {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this > Bootstrap 3

Brilliant exacly what I was looking for, however I had some clashes with the javascript and the bootstrap modal, this fixed it.

```
    $(function() {
    $('.navbar-nav').on('click', function(){ 
        if($('.navbar-header .navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
            $(".navbar-header .navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This worked well for me. Its the same as the accepted answer but fixes the issue related to the desktop/tablet view

```js
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function () {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            $(".navbar-toggle").click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: window.innerWidth <= 767 is better ;) or window.innerWidth < 768

Comment: This should be selected as a top answer. However, this doesn't work with drop downs. I fixed it by replacing selector with: $('.navbar-nav').find('a:not(".dropdown-toggle")')

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('.nav a').click(function () {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: This works for me.  I have a navbar on every kendo view, so I need to close them on the `beforeShow` event.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to use default Bootstrap 3's [collapse.js methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) using the `.navbar-collapse` as the collapsible element you wish to hide as shown below.

Other solutions may cause other undesired problems with the way elements display or function in your web page. Therefore, while some solutions may appear to fix your initial problem it may very well introduce others, so make sure you run thorough testing of your site after any fix.

To see this code in action:

> 1. Press "Run This Code Snippet" below.
> 2. Press "Full Page" button.
> 3. Scale window until drop-down activates.
> 4. Then select a menu option and voila!

Cheers!

```js
$('.nav a').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');  
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="author" content="Franciscus Agnew">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap Navbar Collapse Function</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-expanded="navbar"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>Menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Logo</a>
          </div><!-- navbar-header -->
    
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#staff">Staff</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul><!-- navbar-right -->
          </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
          
        </div><!-- container -->
      </nav><!-- navbar-fixed-top -->
    </header>
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Custom Navbar Collapse Script Solution -->
    <script>
      $('.nav a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');  
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is much better than the currently accepted answer. With that one, I get ghost animations on desktop.

Answer (score 2):

On each dropdown link put data-toggle="collapse" and data-target=".nav-collapse" where nav-collapse is the name you give it to the dropdown list.

```
<ul class="nav" >
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="nav-collapse">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Contact</a></li>
      <!-- dropdown -->
  </ul>
```

This is working perfectly on screen that have a dropdown like mobile screens, but on desktop and tablet it creates a flickr. This is because the .collapsing class is applied. 
To remove the flickr I created a media query and inserted overflow hidden to the collapsing class.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.collapsing {
    overflow: inherit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" to the tag `<a>` worked for me.

```
<div>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a
                    href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" class="nav-link" >Home
                </a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it. If there is a smoother way, please please tell me.

Inside the `<a>` tags where the links for the menu are I added this code:

```
onclick="$('.navbar-toggle').click()"
```

It preserves the slide animation. So in full use it would look like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="topNavController as topNav">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">My Cool Site</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active" onclick="$('.navbar-toggle').click()"><a href="home.html" onclick="$('.navbar-toggle').click()"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html" onclick="$('.navbar-toggle').click()">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

100% working:-

Add in HTML

```
<div id="myMenu" class="nav-collapse">
```

Javascript

```
 $(function(){ 
 var navMain = $("#myMenu");
 navMain.on("click", "a", null, function () {
     navMain.collapse('hide');
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav a').on('click touchstart', function(){ 
        if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
            $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
        }
    });
});
```

// NOTE I added the "touchstart" for mobile touch. touchstart/end has no delay

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.nav a').on('click', function () {

            if ($(".btn-navbar").is(":visible") ){ $(".btn-navbar").trigger("click"); } //bootstrap 2.x
            if ($(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible")) { $(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click"); } //bootstrap 3.x
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body,.nav a").click(function (event) {

    // only do this if navigation is visible, otherwise you see jump in
    //navigation while collapse() iS called 
    if ($(".navbar-collapse").is(":visible") && $(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible")) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have noticed desktop navbars flicker when using this solution:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

A simple solution to that problem is to reference the collapsed navbar only by checking for the presence of 'in':

```
$('.navbar-collapse .nav a').on('click', function(){
    if($('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('in'))
    {
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

This collapses the navbar on click when the navbar is in mobile mode, but will leave alone the desktop version.  This avoids the flickering many people have witnessed occurring on desktop versions.

Additionally, if you have a navbar with *dropdown menus* you won't be able to see these as the navbar will be hidden as soon as you click on them, so if you have dropdown menus (like I do!), use the following:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('dropdown') & $( '.navbar-collapse').hasClass('in'))
    {
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

This looks for the presence of the dropdown class above the link clicked on in the DOM, if it exists, then the link was intending to launch a drop down menu and consequently the menu isn't hidden.  When you click on a link within the dropdown menu, the navbar will hide correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 5.3 - update 2023

### The following works with Bootstrap 5.2 and up:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu-navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link d-lg-none" href="/">
            <span data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu-navbar">Home</span>
            </a>
            <a class="nav-link d-none d-lg-block" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### 2 links in a nav-item

I used 2 links, because if you use `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-menu-navbar"` your menu will "flash/reload" on desktop too, so the first link will hide on lg and wider screens and the second link will do the opposite, hide on screens smaller than lg

Answer (score -1):

This hides nav collapse instead of animating it but same concept as above answer

JS:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function () {
    $("#funk").toggleClass('in collapse');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse" id="funk">
```

I prefer this on single page sites because I use localScroll.js that already animates.

Answer (score -1):

Mobile view: **how to hide toggle navigation in bootstrap + dropdown + jquery + scrollto with navigation items that points to anchors/ids on the same page**, one page template

The issue I was experimenting with any of the above solutions was that they are collapsing only the submenu items, while the navigation menu doesn't collapse.

So I did my thought.. and what can we observe? Well, every time we/the users click an scrollto link, we want the page to scroll to that position and contemporaneously, collapse the menu to restore the page view.

Well... why not to assign this job to the scrollto functions? Easy :-)

So in the two codes

```
// scroll to top action
$('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

and

```
// scroll function
function scrollToID(id, speed){
var offSet = 67;
var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
var mainNav = $('#main-nav');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, speed);
if (mainNav.hasClass("open")) {
    mainNav.css("height", "1px").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
    mainNav.removeClass("open");
}
```

I've just added the same command in both the functions

```
    if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
    $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
}
```

(kudos to one of the above contributors)

like this (the same should be added to both the scrolls)

```
$('.scroll-top').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
if($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') !='none'){
    $(".navbar-toggle").trigger( "click" );
}
});
```

if you wanna see it in action just check it out [**recupero dati da NAS**](http://www.recuperodati.biz/nas/)

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap3 users try the given below code. It worked for me.

```
function close_toggle() {
   if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      $('.nav a').on('click', function(){
          $(".navbar-toggle").click();
      });
   }
   else {
     $('.nav a').off('click');
   }
}
close_toggle();

$(window).resize(close_toggle);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add an id then to each

```
<li> add data-target="myMenu" data-toggle="collapse"
<div id="myMenu" class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active" data-target="myMenu" data-toggle="collapse"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li data-target="myMenu" data-toggle="collapse"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li data-target="myMenu" data-toggle="collapse"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li data-target="myMenu" data-toggle="collapse"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li data-target="myMenu" data-toggle="collapse"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another quick solution for Bootstrap 3.* could be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //
    // Hide collapsed menu on click
    //
    $('.nav a').each(function (idx, obj) {
        var selected = $(obj);

        selected.on('click', function() {
            if (selected.closest('.collapse.in').length > 0) {
                $('.navbar-toggle').click(); //bootstrap 3.x by Richard
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I posted a solution that works with Aurelia here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41465905/6466378

The problem is you can not just add `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#navbar"` to your a elements. And jQuery does not work wenn in an Aurelia or Angular environment.

The best solution for me was to create a custom attribute that listens to the corresponding media query and adds in the `data-toggle="collapse"`attribute if desired:

`<a href="#" ... collapse-toggle-if-less768 data-target="#navbar"> ...`

The custom attribute with Aurelia looks like this:

```js
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject
export class CollapseToggleIfLess768CustomAttribute {
  element: Element;

  constructor(element: Element) {
    this.element = element;
    var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
    mql.addListener((mediaQueryList: MediaQueryList) => this.handleMediaChange(mediaQueryList));
    this.handleMediaChange(mql);
  }

  handleMediaChange(mediaQueryList: MediaQueryList) {
    if (mediaQueryList.matches) {
      var dataToggle = this.element.attributes.getNamedItem("data-toggle");
      if (dataToggle) {
        this.element.attributes.removeNamedItem("data-toggle");
      }
    } else {
      var dataToggle = this.element.attributes.getNamedItem("data-toggle");
      if (!dataToggle) {
        var dataToggle = document.createAttribute("data-toggle");
        dataToggle.value = "collapse";
        this.element.attributes.setNamedItem(dataToggle);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I checked in menu is opened by checking 'in' class and then run the code.

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').on('click', function(){
    if ( $( '.navbar-collapse' ).hasClass('in') ) {
        $('.navbar-toggle').click();
    }
});
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Bootstrap 4, using fullPage.js with a fixed top nav, and tried everything listed here, with mixed results.

- Tried the best, clean way :

  ```
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
  ```

  The menu would collapse, but the href links wouldn't lead anywhere.
- Tried the logical other ways :

  ```
  $('myClickableElements').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse.show").collapse('hide');
    // or
    $(".navbar-collapse.show").collapse('toggle');
    // or
    $('.navbar-toggler').click()
  });
  ```

  There would be some weird behavior because of the touchstart event : the clicked buttons would end up not be the ones I actually clicked, hence breaking the links.
  Plus it would add the .show class to some other unrelated dropdowns in my nav, causing some more weird stuff.
- Tried to change div to li
- Tried to e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation()
- Tried and tried more

Nothing would work.

So, instead, I had the (so far) marvelous idea of doing that :

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
   $(".navbar-collapse.show").collapse('hide');
});
```

I already had stuff in that hashchange function, si I just had to add this line.

It actually does exactly what I want : collapsing the menu when the hash changes (i.e. a click leading somewhere else has occurred). Which is good, cause I can now have links in my menu that won't collapse it.

Who knows, maybe this will help someone in my situation!

And thanks to everyone who has participated in that thread, lots of info to be learned here.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases you will only want to call the toggle function if the toggle button is visible...

```
if ($('.navbar-toggler').is(":visible")) $('.navbar-toggler').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have scrolling problems after using the jQuery solution described above, e.g.

`$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');`

then this is caused by Bootstrap adding the CSS class `overlay-active` in the parent element. This can even go up to your `body` element.

To solve this you have to remove this class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.nav-item').click(function(){
            $('.overlay-active').removeClass('overlay-active');
        });

    });
</script>
```