# Bootstrap 3 fixed top navbar is displaying horizontal scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm doing a fixed top navbar using Bootstrap 3 with mobile first approach.

I'm stuck with an issue when I view on a large screen (eg. menu is not collapsed) and **I click on one of the menu links, a horizontal scroll is appearing on the menu.**

The issue seems to be happening after I added `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` on the navbar-collapsable `div` or also I've tried it with the anchor links too, in order to add the auto close when clicking on a link in Mobile View (small screen).

When I'm using it as Mobile view (small display) it works perfectly and has the auto close when clicking a link which I require.

An example is saved in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/slnKtDkPIrnQIoiZWn3I?p=preview) which you can see.

Anyone can help how to remove that scroll please?

Comment: I'd say you shouldn't add `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"` like that and should add a custom click handler instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203111/bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-doesnt-close-on-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback.

as @cvrebert said, I removed `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse` and instead I've added the following js:

`$(document).on('click.nav', '.navbar-collapse', function (e) {
        if ($(".navbar-header button").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
        }
    });`

This will check that the menu button is visible or not, if its visible it will close the menu.

Thanks.