# how to auto close the bootstrap3's navbar collapse with dart?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dart

which the navbar looks like this:

[image]

i have search the answer about jquery, but i'm not known jquery at all...the html code is :

```
<div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.zhi-tech.com" target="_blank">SmartGas System</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="nav-pills navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li [class.active]="getLinkStyle('')">
                <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/Home']">系统总览</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    账户管理 <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li [class.active]="getLinkStyle('/account_managger/manual_meter')">
                        <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/AccountManualMeter']">人工账单</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li [class.active]="getLinkStyle('/device_manager')">
                <a class="link" [routerLink]="['/DeviceManager']">设备管理</a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled"><a>权限管理</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a>统计信息</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know Bootstrap well. Can you point out how you'd do it in jQuery or plain JS or link to docs that explain what you want to do? Is it about setting an attribute or calling a JS function? Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203111/bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-doesnt-close-on-click ?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto close'? When you click outside the navbar it should hide?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, yes i want to calling such JS function in dart...

Comment: @Martin it means when i click the navbar, it still open, if there have something behind the navbar it will be keep out, for example, the input element with foucus in, the cursor will blink on the navbar...

Comment: @Matrix Ok, can you make a https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ so we can try it?

Comment: @Martin, https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f79dcf984fd15a132308, view it in small size, and click the navbar, it will cover the element as long as user close it