# Mobile menu button do not close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="..."></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#tf-h..." class="scroll">S...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tf-i..." class="scroll">D...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tf-l..." class="scroll">L...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tf-w..." class="scroll">W...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tf-p..." class="scroll">P...</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tf-c..." class="scroll">K...</a></li>
            <li><a href="I...">I...</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Hey everyone,

I have this code and a problem.

When I'm clicking on the menu button, the menu expands. But if I click on a menu link, the menu stays open. What do I have to do, to close it after clicking a link?

EDIT: I already tryed the answers from "[Bootstrap 3 collapsed menu doesn't close on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203111/bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-doesnt-close-on-click)" but they do not solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have the javascript code like this  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> You NEED that with Bootstrap

Comment: I have folloing in my index.html

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

and Version v3.3.2 in bootstrap.min.js & bootstrap.js

Comment: You want to clearly describe why that other question doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `data-toggle="collapse"` to your menu links. So your `li`s will look like:

```
<li><a href="#tf-h..." class="scroll" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">S...</a></li>
```

See [example here](http://www.bootply.com/lbIb5ZaHbq)

Comment: I tryed this, it do not work for me. But thanks for this idea!