# Dropdown links open and close and open again

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bootstrap accordion, and when I click one panel title to open it, instead of just staying open, it opens and then closes and opens again. The same thing is happening with the hamburger menu button at the top of the page (on small screen).

Here is the HTML. I don't really know javascript - I just used bootstrap's plugin. Here's bootstrap's javascript file:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-group my-3" id="accordion1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp; What is TorahMates?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">Typically, TorahMates study once a week for 30-60 minutes. There’s not usually any preparation necessary, especially if you’re using a text. Just be ready at your scheduled, agreed upon time to participate in an engaging discussion on the topic you choose! </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;  Who is TorahMates for?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">TorahMates is a great program for pretty much anyone Jewish, even if you don’t know anything about Judaism. We set up more knowledgeable volunteer mentors with “students” with less background. Usually, both partners find they gain tremendously from their study together. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;  What topics can I study?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body"> It’s up to you! You can study any topic that interests you, as long as it has something to do with Judaism, Torah, Jewish law or faith, Jewish History, Hebrew, prayers... you get the idea. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseFour1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;  How will you choose my partner?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">We have a large database of men and women who’ve signed up that we’ll use to find the perfect match for you. Some of the things we look for are common interests, ages, and cultural backgrounds. Often, these partnerships develop into far more than routine study sessions. Many of our TorahMates are now close friends too!</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseFive1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span> &nbsp; How do TorahMates go about studying?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFive1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Most TorahMates study over the phone but FaceTime or the like is also a great option. Where possible, some TorahMates even study in person. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseSix1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;  Will you supply the books/study text or do I need to get my own?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSix1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Once you’ve decided what topic you want to learn, your TorahMates coordinator will suggest various titles and authors to support that topic. Not everyone learns from a text, but many do. We’ll supply each of you with one free book per year of learning.</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseEight1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;  What happens if my partnership is not working out?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseEight1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Your coordinator will work with both partners to smooth out any issues that may arise. If nothing can be worked out or if it’s just not a match, we can find new partners for each TorahMate.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseNine1"><span class="question">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;  What is the mileage program? How do I log in to it?</a></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseNine1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">The mileage program is a nice perk through which TorahMates can earn <a href="/mileage/peekPrizes.asp" target="_blank">great prizes</a> by logging in their sessions by date and number of minutes learned. You can log in online, by phone or by text. Your TorahMates coordinator can show you how. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the link to the page:
http://torahmates.org/junior/index.php#faq

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your JavaScript and HTML code.

Comment: We don't debug live sites. Post the relevant code here.

Comment: Please provide your HTML and JS code.

Comment: I edited my post above.

Comment: bootstrap bug?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203111/bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-doesnt-close-on-click/22917099

Comment: That is not the same as my question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an include file with duplicate scripts running on the page, which was causing the issue.