# Bootstrap 5.1.3 navbar not collapse after click

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

The menu in the mobile version opens and works, but after clicking on the menu item the navbar does not collapse... I got the css, js and navbar from the bootstrap site:

Where is the problem?

```html
<head>
      
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: For me, its working. i can open and close the nav bar then where is the issue?

Comment: In the mobile version if you try to put a link in the a tag and then click the navbar it doesn't collapse

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bqv0dkn9/ check here. its working after putting link.

Comment: If you create a div with an id = "a" inside and in the href enter #a, then href = "# a" and then hit the menu item the navbar should take you to that div closing, but the navbar won't close ... I hope I explained myself

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your  tags.  What it'll do is, trigger a click event on the hamburger button, which will cause the menu to collapse.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.navbar-nav li a').on("click", function() {
          console.log("menu clicked");
          $('button.navbar-toggler').click();
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" data-bs-toggle="collapse"></div>
```

I've added the `data-bs-toggle='collapse'` to main navbar as shown above.

I think that the button needs a target to collapse so i've added `data-bs-toggle='collapse'`

It worked for me. hope will for you too.

Comment: <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" data-bs-toggle="collapse">

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203111/bootstrap-3-collapsed-menu-doesnt-close-on-click

Comment: We need to add both ‘data-bs-toggle’ and ‘data-bs-target’ to the event receiver element. 

Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/crazygo/swj2tqkL/2/

There is an official document available at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#example