# How do I get navbar toggle button to dropdown on first click, rather than dropping, disappearing, and then having to click again?

Tags: jquery, navbar

When my site is on small screens and shows a navbar collapsed toggle button, I wrote some jquery to hide the navbar upon a click of menu item, then upon clicking the navbar toggle button again I wanted it to simply show itself again so the user could choose another menu item. What happens is that after the first hide() event, it takes 2 clicks of the navbar toggle button to display the menu. How can I get it so that there is only 1 click needed? Here is code and link to site:

```
 $('.select').on('click', function() {
      $('#navigation').hide();
    });

    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('#navigation').show();
    });
```

http://mattparmanswebsites.herokuapp.com/
(shrink screen below width of 700 to see collapsed menu issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Twitter Bootstrap nav collapse on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680543/hide-twitter-bootstrap-nav-collapse-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.toggle` function to show/hide the `#navigation`.

```
$('.select').on('click', function() {
    $('#navigation').toggle();
});
```

Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jn9xye13/).

Comment: Thanks, I did try toggle. It actually made the problem worse. Instead of simply toggling, it now requires 2-3 clicks to toggle after the first hide() is triggered....

Comment: You don't need the hide on click event. Replace all of the code you posted above with what I provided. If it doesn't work, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: With your code, once the first click to #navigation occurs, the toggle is triggered, but then the user cannot toggle again after that. Something must be breaking or not selecting properly. That's where I got stuck.

Comment: I see what you're doing now. You're using the Bootstrap navbar and are closing it in a non-Bootstrap way. Check out the accepted answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680543/hide-twitter-bootstrap-nav-collapse-on-click).

Answer (score 0):

Simply toggle the event:

```
$(".select").click(function(){
    $("#navigation").toggle();
});
```