# Close a bootstrap menu upon selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want my bootstrap and angular app menu to collapse with animation after selection, and then let the handler do navigation.  (I'm mystified why a menu wouldn't close by default on selection).

I've found how to do jquery stuff in an angular app, and how to do menu stuff in a jquery app, so I'm trying to combine the solutions to these two questions:

- (menu, but not angular) [Hide Twitter Bootstrap nav collapse on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680543/hide-twitter-bootstrap-nav-collapse-on-click?lq=1)
- (anugular, but not menu) [How to trigger ng-click [AngularJS] programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447374/how-to-trigger-ng-click-angularjs-programmatically)

My html looks like this...

```
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/" ng-bind="title"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" ng-click="selected(menuItem)"><p ng-bind="menuItem.name"></p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And so, I think my JS should look like this...

```
$scope.selected = function(menuItem) {
    console.log(menuItem);
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element('#js-navbar-collapse').triggerHandler('click');
      }, 10);
};
```

But after trying every selector and several jquery methods, I can't make it work.  The result is the same each time:  the menu stays open, and all I get on the UI is a little flash of the menu icon.

Comment: you do not do dom manioulation in controller. You need to do a directive

Comment: Other than that, if you can create a JSFiddle it would be helpful