# bootstrap 4.3.1 navbar not collapsing on link click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I apologize in advice for being another bootstrap navbar question but I could not find a solution in the questions already answered on here.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Using bootstrap 4.1.3.

Problem: Navbar not collapsing on link click.

The following is a link which is inside of the `<head>` tag (placed before the style.css, if the matters):

`<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

And here are two scripts placed just before the `</body>` tag:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

`<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

This is my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

I see what you're saying now:

Bootstrap has attributes to be applied to the  tags in order for the functionality to work correctly on the navbar.

The attributes needed are the data-toggle and data-target attributes.

Change your 'a' tags to look like this:

```
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
```

working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6cfL9m0/

This question has actually already been answered here:
[How to hide collapsible Bootstrap 4 navbar on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401606/how-to-hide-collapsible-bootstrap-4-navbar-on-click)

Comment: Agreed - I've just tried the same code in Codepen and it worked perfectly: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxrgdr

Comment: Hi @RobSinton and Jonny, I opened up your CodePen and Jonny's jsfiddle but when I clicked on a link nothing collapsed. I should have specified on a link click.

Comment: Hi connorocampo, I have now updated my answer, this better answers what you were looking for

Comment: Think I misinterpreted the question - I assumed that you were clicking the navbar toggle and it wasn't closing as opposed to clicking one of the links in the navbar. My bad!

Comment: Hi again @Jonny - thanks for the reference. I actually tried the first solution in the answer and it did not work. I just tried the second one though and it worked! I added the code in between `<script>` tags before the `</body>`. Thank you for answering and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @RobSinton it was my bad for not specifying in the question! I did a ninja edit and specified after reading your comment.