# How do I get nav menu to collapse on mobile but not on desktop?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to get my `nav` menu to collapse on mobile devices, but not on desktops.

Adding `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"` seems to work, but then `nav` items also collapse when they're clicked on a desktop device.

```
<div class="py-0 px-3 fixed-top">
    <nav class="navbar container navbar-transparent navbar-padded navbar-expand-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Logo
        </a>    
        <button
            class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right d-md-none"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarResponsive"
            aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-uppercase" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                    <a class="nav-link"href="#link1">link1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#link2">link2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data-target to the mobile collapsed version: `.navbar-collapse.show`

```
   <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#link1">link1</a>
   </li>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/qBh0qJYekK

---

Related: [How to hide collapsible Bootstrap 4 navbar on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401606/how-to-hide-collapsible-bootstrap-4-navbar-on-click/42401686#42401686)