# Programmatically Collapse Bootstrap Navbar in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I'm using Bootstrap's navbar and I can get it to collapse successfully by using `data-toggle` and `data-target` on each `li` element.

This SO answer shows a way to do this without having to alter each `li`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42401686/279516

This is my navbar with two of the `li` elements:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/servers">Servers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/servers">Variables</a>
    </li>
```

I'm close to getting this done in my Angular 8 Typescript file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const navbarItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-nav>li');
    navbarItems.forEach(navbarItem => {
      navbarItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
      })
    });
  }
}
```

The issue is the last line:

> Property `collapse` does not exist on type `element`.

First, what should I do to get this to work?
Second, is there a better way?

I've tried casting `navbar` as different types of HTML elements, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you try this `(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.navbar-collapse')).collapse('hide');`?

Comment: I just tried it. Same error.

Comment: Have you considered using the Bootstrap widgets for Angular? The functionality you seek is provided all OOB: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

Comment: @jcruz I'm already using Bootstrap, and it's collapsing when hitting the hamburger menu icon. I'm just trying to enhance it by collapsing it when clicking an item within the navbar.

Comment: @BobHorn the way you are doing it does not follow the MVC/MVVM pattern so its not clear that you are using ng-bootstrap. Anyway, it is best practice to use the pattern similar to the Jens answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more the Angular way. Like this:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="showMenu=!showMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'show':showMenu}">
     ...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by removing 'show' from the class list, shown on the last line here.

(I'm still not sure if this is a good approach, but it's working.)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const navbarItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-nav>li');
    navbarItems.forEach(navbarItem => {
      navbarItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar-collapse');
        navbar.classList.remove('show');
      })
    });
  }
}
```