# How to fix blinking navbar after click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I tried to use this solution ([Hide Twitter Bootstrap nav collapse on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680543/hide-twitter-bootstrap-nav-collapse-on-click)) to hide nav collapse automatically when clicking. It's working correctly when nav is collapsed but when I'm using site on desktops (exactly when nav is not collapsed) nav is blinking.

**Code:**

```js
$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
  $(".btn-navbar").click(); //bootstrap 2.x
  $(".navbar-toggle").click() //bootstrap 3.x by Richard
});
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 70px 0;
}
#section-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}
#section-1 {
  margin-top: 51px;
  /* height of header-navbar */
}
#section-1,
#section-2,
#section-3 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#section-1">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#section-2">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#section-3">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<div class="block" id="section-1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.block -->

<div id="section-white"></div>

<div class="block" id="section-2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.block -->

<div id="section-white"></div>

<div class="block" id="section-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Hello World
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.block -->
```

You can try it here - [Desktop results](https://jsfiddle.net/hwavo6u1/embedded/result/) and this is source code - [source code](https://jsfiddle.net/hwavo6u1/)

Earlier I used this solution in Bootstrap 2.3.2 and haven't got any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**JS**

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Check the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwavo6u1/3/)**.

Also check this answer: [Close responsive navbar automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248194/close-responsive-navbar-automatically)

Comment: Your link had an extra `/` at the end of it and was broken. Fixed that for ya.

Comment: Problem is fixed now. Thank you for fast help!

Comment: This solves it. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't cause blinking but the bootstrap implementation without JS does? Thanks again.